# Azure Container App with Nginx reverse proxy returns connection failure

Tags: azure, http, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, azure-container-apps

I have a Nginx reverse proxy configured in front of a service. They are both Docker images, and I uploaded them as Azure Container Apps.

I have the following configuration for the reverse proxy:

```
location /api/my-service/ {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-service_api.log main;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header "Connection" "";
    proxy_pass http://my-service/;    
}
```

If I run `curl -ik -X GET 'https://localhost/api/my-service/some-endpoint'` from inside the Nginx container console, I get the expected response from my proxied service. I get the same expected result if I use the public URL of the Contaier App while inside the container (instead of `localhost`). The problem is that if I try to execute the request from my computer, I get a `503` error with a response saying `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried and the latest reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111`

I was previously getting the same error when executing the request from inside the Nginx container, but it got fixed after I added `proxy_http_version 1.1;` to the Nginx `location` configuration for my service. This makes me think something between my external request and the Nginx Container App might be doing something with the `HTTP` version, but I haven't found any configuration or log to confirm this.

Since from inside the container the reverse proxy works, am I right to assume the problem is related to the Container App configuration? What could the problem be?

### Extra information

The ingress is enabled for accepting traffic from anywhere, ingress type `HTTP`, and transport `auto`.
I'm using a certificate from Cloudflare, used to secure the traffic between Cloudflare and the Container App. At one point I though maybe Cloudflare was doing something when proxying the request, but if I access direcly to the Container App URL (skipping Cloudflare), I still get the same error.

Comment: what's the configured `transport` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/containerapps?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#ingress) ? Also any custom domain / cert you are using  ?

Comment: @Thomas, it's currently in `auto`, although I tryed using HTTP/1 at some point and it gave me the same error. I'm using a custom domain with a certificate from Cloudflare. I'm able to execute the request with `https` from inside the container, so I had discarded the certificate as a possible cause.

Comment: so you domain and cert are at cloud flare ? cloudflare doing tls termination ? and cloud flare is configured to send request to the container appout of the box domain `<UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER>.<REGION_NAME>.azurecontainerapps.io` ?

Comment: most of issue i had in the past with WAF integration wi9th container are certificated related tbh. if you call your container app with the .azurecontainerapps.io is it working fine ?

Comment: @Thomas, when I call the container with its `azurecontainerapps.io` URL I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue, so I'll leave my solution here in case someone else has something similar happening to them.

My Container App is configured so it doesn't accept insecure connections, so in my Nginx configuration I was listening only to the `443` port:

```
server {
    ...
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
}
```

For some reason, adding `listen 80;` fixed the error and now the reverse proxy is working in the Container App.

I'm using `http` internally to connect to my proxied service (instead of `https`), so maybe that's something to consider.